# Flutter web Firebase initialization error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

When I start the flutter web app I get this error:

> [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
> Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { auth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-auth.js'
    import { firestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-firestore.js'  
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxx",
      authDomain: "xxx",
      projectId: "xxx",
      storageBucket: "xxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxx",
      appId: "xxx"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>  
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
         ...
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see firebase is initialized in the index.html file.
I have installed all the needed libraries, this is the list:

- firebase_auth: ^3.4.2
- cloud_firestore: ^3.3.0
- firebase_core: ^1.19.2

Should I init firebase in flutter?

Comment: These days it is more common to initialize Firebase inside your `main.dart` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (kIsWeb) 
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "xxx",
        appId: "xxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxx",
        projectId: "xxx",
      ),
    );
else
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Add the above code in your main.dart file.
(kIsWeb will check whether the application is running on the web)